# ERROR Error: NG02200: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: angular, typescript, database, fetch, rapidapi

I'm trying to fetch datas from rapidapi but i get this ERROR message:

"ERROR Error: NG02200: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables, such as Arrays. Did you mean to use the keyvalue pipe?"

That is my html:

```
<div class="row details mt-3" *ngFor="let coin of coinsList">
  <div class="col-3">
    <a href=""><img src="..." class="mb-3"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <p>{{coin.name}}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 text-center">
    <p>Price</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 text-end">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The console.warn works but the *NgFor don't

My code is this, I'm using Angular 14.2.10:

```
export class CryptoListComponent implements OnInit {
    coinsList: any
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getCoinsList()
    }

    // interface Response { results: Coins[] }

    getCoinsList() {
        let options = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'X-RapidAPI-Key': '4c10ffb7eemsha0cedbbe44177e3p1b0292jsn06e3680b3b7b',
                'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'cryptocurrency-markets.p.rapidapi.com'
            }
        }
        return this.http.get('https://cryptocurrency-markets.p.rapidapi.com/coins?page=1', options).subscribe((res) => {
            this.coinsList = res
            console.warn(this.coinsList);
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems like the response from the API is an object, but the *ngFor directive expects an iterable. One way to fix this issue is to extract the array of coins from the response object and assign it to the coinsList variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the ngFor an array, here you're giving it an object, try:

```
this.coinsList = res.results
```